# What is wrong with this Java for HDInsight Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to find out why the below Java does not work when I try to run it on hadoop.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

public class PageStat implements Tool {
private Configuration conf;

@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Job job = new Job(getConf());
    String jobName = "Page visit statistics MR";
    job.setJobName(jobName);

    job.setJarByClass(PageStat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.setMapperClass(PageStat.PageStatMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(PageStat.PageStatReducer.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setNumReduceTasks(job.getConfiguration().getInt("num.reducer", 1));

    int status =  job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    return status;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new PageStat(), args);
    System.exit(exitCode);
}

public void setConf(Configuration conf) {
   this.conf = conf;
}

public Configuration getConf() {
    return conf;
}

public static class PageStatMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private Text keyHolder = new Text();
    private IntWritable valueHolder = new IntWritable();

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] items  =  value.toString().split(",");
        if (items.length == 3) {
            String url = items[1];
            keyHolder.set(url);
            Integer duration = Integer.parseInt(items[2]);
            valueHolder.set(duration);
            context.write(keyHolder, valueHolder);
        } else {
            context.getCounter("Error", "invalidData").increment(1);
        }
    }        
}   

public static class PageStatReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    private Text keyHolder = new Text();
    private IntWritable valueHolder = new IntWritable();
    private String statType;
    private int count;
    private int totalTime;
    private int avTime;

    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        statType = conf.get("page.stat");
    }

    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        count = 0;
        totalTime = 0;
        for (IntWritable value : values){
            ++count;
            totalTime += value.get();
        } 
        avTime = totalTime / count;

        keyHolder.set(key);
        if (statType.equals("average")){
            valueHolder.set(avTime);
        } else {
            valueHolder.set(totalTime);
        }
        context.write(keyHolder, valueHolder);
    }
}    

}
```

**The error is:**

> c:\hadoop-training\tutorial02-jobtracker>hadoop jar PageStat.jar
>   PageStat jobtra cker/input/visit_5000000.txt jobtracker/output
>   13/07/29 11:24:50 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to
>   process : 1  log4j:ERROR Failed to rename
>   [c:\Hadoop\hadoop-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT\logs/hadoop.log] t o
>   [c:\Hadoop\hadoop-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT\logs/hadoop.log.2013-07-26]. 13/07/29
>   11:24:51 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library 
>   13/07/29 11:24:51 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not
>   loaded 13/07/29 11:24:54 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job:
>   job_201307261340_0001 13/07/29 11:24:55 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0%
>   reduce 0% 13/07/29 11:25:24 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 1% reduce 0% 
>   13/07/29 11:25:27 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 6% reduce 0% 13/07/29
>   11:25:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 14% reduce 0% 13/07/29 11:25:35
>   INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 22% reduce 0% 13/07/29 11:25:38 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:  map 31% reduce 0%  13/07/29 11:25:41 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:  map 35% reduce 0% 13/07/29 11:25:44 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:  map 44% reduce 0% 13/07/29 11:25:47 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:  map 50% reduce 0% 13/07/29 11:26:03 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:  map 60% reduce 0%  13/07/29 11:26:06 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:  map 64% reduce 0% 13/07/29 11:26:09 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:  map 69% reduce 0% 13/07/29 11:26:12 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:  map 76% reduce 0% 13/07/29 11:26:15 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:  map 81% reduce 0%  13/07/29 11:26:18 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:  map 85% reduce 0% 13/07/29 11:26:21 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:  map 87% reduce 0% 13/07/29 11:26:24 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:  map 92% reduce 0% 13/07/29 11:26:27 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:  map 94% reduce 0%  13/07/29 11:26:30 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:  map 96% reduce 0% 13/07/29 11:26:33 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:  map 97% reduce 0% 13/07/29 11:26:37 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:  map 99% reduce 8% 13/07/29 11:26:40 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 8%  13/07/29 11:26:46 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 25% 13/07/29 11:26:54 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201307261340_0001_r_0 00000_0,
>   Status : FAILED java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at PageStat$PageStatReducer.reduce(PageStat.java:120)
>            at PageStat$PageStatReducer.reduce(PageStat.java:96)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:177)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:651
>   )
>            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:418)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:271)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInforma
>   tion.java:1135)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:265)
>
> 13/07/29 11:26:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%  13/07/29
>   11:27:05 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 8% 13/07/29 11:27:08
>   INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 33% 13/07/29 11:27:10 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201307261340_0001_r_0 00000_1,
>   Status : FAILED  java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at PageStat$PageStatReducer.reduce(PageStat.java:120)
>           at PageStat$PageStatReducer.reduce(PageStat.java:96)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:177)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:651
>   )
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:418)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:271)
>            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInforma 
>   tion.java:1135)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:265)
>
> 13/07/29 11:27:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0% 13/07/29
>   11:27:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 8% 13/07/29 11:27:23
>   INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 25%  13/07/29 11:27:25 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201307261340_0001_r_0 00000_2,
>   Status : FAILED java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at PageStat$PageStatReducer.reduce(PageStat.java:120)
>           at PageStat$PageStatReducer.reduce(PageStat.java:96)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:177)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:651
>   )
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:418)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:271)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInforma 
>   tion.java:1135)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:265)
>
> 13/07/29 11:27:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0% 13/07/29
>   11:27:38 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 25% 13/07/29 11:27:41
>   INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%  13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201307261340_0001 13/07/29
>   11:27:43 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 24 13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=4  13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=179086 13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces wai ting after
>   reserving slots (ms)=0 13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   Total time spent by all maps waitin  g after reserving slots (ms)=0
>   13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=4
>   13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=4
>   13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed reduce tasks=1 
>   13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=106513 13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   FileSystemCounters 13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   FILE_BYTES_READ=179504086 13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   HDFS_BYTES_READ=254931072  13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=359099432 13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO mapred.JobClient: 
>   File Input Format Counters 13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   Bytes Read=254930544 13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   Map-Reduce Framework  13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map
>   output materialized bytes=17949 9502 13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0 13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=5000000  13/07/29 11:27:43
>   INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=85 1607552
>   13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=10000000
>   13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output
>   bytes=169499478  13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time
>   spent (ms)=81308 13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total
>   committed heap usage (bytes)= 746323968 13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=988  401664
>   13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
>   13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output
>   records=5000000 13/07/29 11:27:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=528

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, you need to use the -D flag to execute:

```
-Dpage.stat=total
```

You'll likely see an error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

That's not the full answer, I'm still getting to the bottom of it myself.

Answer (score 0):

The line numbers in the stack trace don't seem to line up with the source code posted.  Has the code changed since this run?

The NullPointerException may be occurring on the if (statType...) line.  I don't see anything setting "page.stat" in the configuration, either hard-coded in the run method or passed as an argument in the job submission.  This would cause the statType member to be initialized to null.